# trust me on that score -- what does that mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Source: [CompTIA A+ Certification All-in-One Exam Guide, 9th Edition (Exam 220-901 & 220-902) by Mike Meyers (2016)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/125958951X)

Example:

> Every company has some form of dress code for techs. Figure 2-2 shows
>   Ford dressed in a fairly typical example, with a company polo shirt, khaki pants, and dark shoes (**trust me on that score**).

What does that expression mean?

Comment: on that score= in that regard, on that subject, about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase "on this score" or "on that score" means "on that matter" or "regarding that subject." It is a colloquial idiom, and in the example you gave the author is basically saying "trust me on that", although his exact meaning on what you should trust him about is a bit unclear.